# Why does SARIMA accuracy increase?

Tags: python, machine-learning, graph, prediction, arima

I am trying to get my hands on ARIMA and SARIMA.
I have got a dataset of sandwiches sold at the coast.

[image: Data + differencing]

In the image above is my data shown + the differencing i am using to make it stationary.

```
smodel = auto_arima(train, start_p=1, start_q=1,
                     test='adf',
                     max_p=3, max_q=3, m=12,
                     start_P=0, seasonal=True,
                     d=None, D=1, trace=True,
                     error_action='ignore',  
                     suppress_warnings=True, 
                     stepwise=True)
```

Above I am using auto_arima to fit my model.

```
  n_periods = 6
fitted, confint = smodel.predict(n_periods=n_periods, return_conf_int=True)
index_of_fc = pd.date_range(train.index[-1], periods = n_periods, freq='MS')

# make series for plotting purpose
fitted_series = pd.Series(fitted, index=index_of_fc)
lower_series = pd.Series(confint[:, 0], index=index_of_fc)
upper_series = pd.Series(confint[:, 1], index=index_of_fc)

# Plot
plt.plot(train)
plt.plot(fitted_series, color='darkgreen')
plt.fill_between(lower_series.index, 
                 lower_series, 
                 upper_series, 
                 color='k', alpha=.15)

plt.title("SARIMA - Final Forecast")
plt.show()
```

Here I am plotting my train data + my prediction which gives me the following result(I still don't know why it skips one month in the graphs but the numbers are correct):

[image: result]

At the end I am testing my accuracy like this:

```
  # Accuracy metrics
def forecast_accuracy(forecast, actual):
    mape = np.mean(np.abs(forecast - actual)/np.abs(actual))  # MAPE
    me = np.mean(forecast - actual)             # ME
    mae = np.mean(np.abs(forecast - actual))    # MAE
    mpe = np.mean((forecast - actual)/actual)   # MPE
    rmse = np.mean((forecast - actual)**2)**.5  # RMSE
    corr = np.corrcoef(forecast, actual)[0,1]   # corr
    mins = np.amin(np.hstack([forecast[:,None], 
                              actual[:,None]]), axis=1)
    maxs = np.amax(np.hstack([forecast[:,None], 
                              actual[:,None]]), axis=1)
    minmax = 1 - np.mean(mins/maxs)             # minmax
    acf1 = acf(fitted-test)[1]                      # ACF1
    return({'mape':mape, 'me':me, 'mae': mae, 
            'mpe': mpe, 'rmse':rmse, 'acf1':acf1, 
            'corr':corr, 'minmax':minmax})

forecast_accuracy(fitted, test.values)
```

And this is my result:

```
{'mape': 0.03461030567300854,
 'me': 6.729205725022392,
 'mae': 17.97150355923618,
 'mpe': 0.016813031496317913,
 'rmse': 20.42619043264491,
 'acf1': -0.13837977897549658,
 'corr': 0.9789628479818636,
 'minmax': 0.033630138432890866}
```

Now, correct me if I am wrong but the MAPE here says 0.034 which basically says that my prediction is around 96.6% accurate.

I have tested this for different time frames (predicting 3 months ahead and 5 months) but the thing I can't manage to understand is that the accuracy for 5 months is higher than 3. Because this seems odd to me I really would like to know if any of you guys have an explanation for this. Maybe my model is not correct? I am just starting with ARIMA and my theory is that auto_arima does not difference the data and there is still a trend but that is just a guess and I don't know how to implement that.

Any help is much appreciated!

(Oh and if anyone knows why my graph skips 1 month, please let me know as well! I know it has to do something with the following line but I am not sure how to plot it otherwise)

```
index_of_fc = pd.date_range(train.index[-1], periods = n_periods, freq='MS')
```